# Fakeroot 1.25 error on configure.ac

Tags: fakeroot

I´m trying to install fakeroot, but when I run `autoconf` to create a configure file the output is this:

```
configure.ac:7: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:8: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_MAINTAINER_MODE
configure.ac:595: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_CONDITIONAL
```

After that, I run `./configure` , this is the output

```
./configure: line 2236: syntax error near unexpected token `2.1a'
./configure: line 2236: `LT_PREREQ(2.1a)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Installation of fakeroot should be fairly easy. I'm unsure what you've tried so far.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fakeroot -y
```

Check if this works.